# C++11 in class initialization for non-static data member

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a class `Foo` like this:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

Then I define a second class:

```
struct Bar {
    Foo bar{1, 2}; // error C2661: no overloaded function takes 2 arguments
};
```

The code `Foo bar{1, 2}` works fine if `bar` is not a class member:

```
int main() {
    Foo bar{1, 2}; // OK
}
```

Is there anything wrong in the code of class `Bar`?

Comment: Which version of MSVC are you using?

Comment: @chris visual studio 2013 RC

Comment: Odd, I think it's a bug. Clang does fine with it.

Comment: `Non-static data member initializers` was supposed to be in MSVC 2013 RTM. However, I just tried it with MSVC 2013 just released, and your code fails, so it looks like there is still a long way to go.

Comment: @JesseGood, Well, `int i{};` works in RC.

Comment: @chris: Yeah, if you add a ctor `Foo(int, int){}` it also works, but not aggregate initialization it seems.

Comment: @JesseGood, Yeah, but only when combined with non-static data member initializers.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with your code.  It's a [compiler bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/792161/constructor-initializer-list-does-not-support-braced-init-list-form).

Both clang++ and g++ process these qualified list initializers correctly. See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d45e3645eec0476 for g++ demonstrating correct behavior.

Comment: Is there already a bug report for this? It would add more value to your answer if you could locate it.

Comment: Done and added as a link.  Thanks for the suggestion.