# In-class member initialization with an initializer list using uniform initialization syntax?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, uniform-initialization, in-class-initialization

I am trying to compile the following with MSVC2013:

```
class SomeClass
{
    struct SomeStruct { bool a,b,c; };
    SomeStruct ss{false, false, false};
}
```

The compiler gives me the following error: `SomeClass::SomeStruct::SomeStruct: no overloaded function takes 3 arguments.`

If I change the code to this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    struct SomeStruct { bool a,b,c; };
    SomeStruct ss{{false, false, false}};
}
```

the program compiles and runs fine. Is this a problem with the compiler, or do I not understand the syntax? From what I've been reading, the first version should compile.

Comment: What compiler are you using? This compiles fine on `gcc 4.9` and `clang TRUNK`.

Comment: Compiler Bug. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474759/c11-in-class-initialization-for-non-static-data-member and http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/792161/constructor-initializer-list-does-not-support-braced-init-list-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the responsible grammar from N3797:

```
// after a member declaration:
braced-or-equal-initializer-list:
  = initializer-clause
  braced-init-list

braced-init-list:
  { initializer-list ,OPT }
  { }

initializer-list:
  initializer-clause
  initializer-list, initializer-clause

initializer-clause:
  assignment-expression
  braced-init-list
```

So I'd say the first statement is correct and it is indeed accepted by
a recent `gcc` and `clang`.

Answer (score 1):

If to place semicolons as it is required

```
class SomeClass
{
    struct SomeStruct { bool a,b,c; };
    SomeStruct ss{false, false, false};
};
```

then it seems that it is a bug of the MS VC++ 2013 compiler. At least the code is compiled successfully at www.ideone.com.

Structire SomeStruct is an aggregate and should be initialized using an initializer list.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo in the question. Thanks, updating now.